# Detrended correspondence analysis

Tags: ecology, correspondence-analysis

I have relative abundance data of monkey species in 4 different types of habitat. I would like to use detrended correspondence analysis. Is this a correct way to display my data? If so, how should I enter the data?

Comment: Seem like a reasonable plan. Worry about the detrended after you've got the basic correspondence analysis going. But what do you want to 'enter the data' *into*?

Comment: Can you add more information here, Carla? I don't know if this question is answerable at present.

Comment: @gung I'm aware of what it is - it's a somewhat old school version of CA that tries to undo the arch effect.  In the `vegan` package it's called `decorana`, I believe after the old software that made it popular.

Comment: My hope was that we would learn what the data was going into. If it were R I would recommend looking at the vegan documentation. If into SPSS I wouldn't be so sure what to recommend (if you can even do it there).

Comment: @gung not a problem

Comment: But how many areas do you have? What is your question really?